# Make a overlay appear on text hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, overlay

I'm looking for a way to make my background image darken by hovering over an anchor within the div container that the background image is attached to.

There has been an instance where it did work but there was a enormous amount of flickering when the mouse was moved within the anchor.

Comment: can you share a demo or code

Answer (score 0):

well, when you hover your anchor inside hover attributes you have to change linear gradient of your background according to what you want! check out linear gradient css 3 attribute for backgrounds!

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript for it.

HTML:

```
<a href="something.example.com/something" onmousehover="darkenIt(this);" />
```

CSS:

```
a{
background-image: url("img/image.jpg");
}
```

The JavaScript:

```
function darkenIt(x){
    x.style.backgroundImage = 'url("img/dark-image.jpg");';
}
```

I don't know how to darken a photo using CSS. Thus, I shown you the code with two different images. If you know how to do it, you can use it.

You can use only CSS for it too. You can use `a:hover` after using `a` class.

Enjoy :D